# sharing data of parent controllers between two child controllers

Tags: angularjs, parent-child, controllers

I am trying to share data between two controllers (child1 and child2) which are children of one common controller (parent).
index.html is :

```
<div ng-controller="parent">
    <ul>
    <p>Parent controller</p>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            {{item.id}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-controller="child1">
        <ul>
            <p>First DIV :</p>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                {{item.id}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="child2">
        <ul>
            <p>Second DIV :</p>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                {{item.id}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have defined three controllers as (parent, child1 and child2) :

```
   var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('parent',['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {'id':1},
        {'id':2},
        {'id':3},
        {'id':4}
    ];

    $scope.items.push({'id':10});

    $scope.myfun = function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $scope.items.push({'id':20});
            alert("inserting 20....!");
        },3000);
    }

    $scope.myfun(); 
}]);

myApp.controller('child1', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = $scope.$parent.items;

}]);

myApp.controller('child2', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = $scope.$parent.items;
}]);
```

But the page is not showing anything. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: may be you forgot `ng-app` attribute

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have assigned ng-app="myApp" in <HTML> tag.

Comment: can you put your code on plnkr.co and give us a link?

Comment: `<li ng-repeat="items in item">` should be `<li ng-repeat="item in items">`

Comment: @CodeHater. Thanks a lot. It was a stupid mistake. I have one doubt now, if $scope in parent controllers keeps changing dynamically now, will those changes be reflected in both DIVs too?

Comment: Yes. They surely will.

Comment: Thanks @CodeHater, it is working. Now I want to assign something to parent $scope dynamically and once it works, I will replace that assignment to HTTP call.

Comment: hi @CodeHater, it is not working, I changed the value of $scope.items in parent controller dynamically but the changes are not getting reflected in any of the DIV tags. I called a function inside parent controller which adds one more key-value pair to items in parent scope. But the lists on index.html <li ng-repeat="item in items"> are not been able to update with the new entry. I also tried to check the same with parent scope, by adding a list outside both the children DIV but inside parent DIV, but still the list does not show the new entry even if items gets updated. How to achieve that????

Comment: Could you create a fiddle?

Comment: @CodeHater : Yes. I have updated the code just now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use angular's `$timeout` service instead of setTimeout:

```
myApp.controller('parent',['$scope','$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.items = [
        {'id':1},
        {'id':2},
        {'id':3},
        {'id':4}
    ];

    $scope.items.push({'id':10});

    $scope.myfun = function() {
       $timeout(function(){
            $scope.items.push({'id':20});
            alert("inserting 20....!");
        },3000);
    }

    $scope.myfun(); 
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you @CodeHater. Just out of curiosity, why is your name CodeHater....??!!!!

Comment: Bwahaahaha! Coz I am one :D